# Query syntax error on MySqlCommand

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net, syntax-error

I'm using MySqlCommand for perform query insert in my `vb.net` application, now I've this query:

```
UPDATE primo_appointments SET 
  book_datetime = @parameter1, 
  start_datetime = @parameter2, 
  end_datetime = @parameter3, 
  notes = @parameter4, 
  hash = @parameter5, 
  is_unavailable = @parameter6 
WHERE hash = xqA5jdsFBLPTrvy5kKHfgXBZdv9Hs2Ld 
  AND lastUpdated = 12-01-2016 15:53:47.3978486
```

when I do: `.ExecuteNonQuery()` this error appear:

> you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15:53:47.3978486' at line 1.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lastUpdated` and `hash` is not enclosed in single quotes which is the cause of your error.

The fix for this is *not* to enclose it in quotes, but to use a parameter for these values as well as the others:

```
UPDATE primo_appointments SET 
  book_datetime = @parameter1, 
  start_datetime = @parameter2, 
  end_datetime = @parameter3, 
  notes = @parameter4, 
  hash = @parameter5, 
  is_unavailable = @parameter6 
WHERE hash = @oldHashString
  AND lastUpdated = @lastUpdatedDate
```

When you use a parameterised list, you don't have to remember whether a field needs to be surrounded by quotes or not - this is handled for you. It also protects you from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: It is strange how many apparently think a parameter wont  work on the WHERE clause

Comment: The same parameter if inserted as @param work, but if I execute the query without put Where parameter into the parametizer value won't work.

Answer (score 0):

your varchar should between 2 `'`, you query should be:

```
UPDATE primo_appointments SET book_datetime = @parameter1, 
start_datetime = @parameter2, end_datetime = @parameter3, 
notes = @parameter4, hash = @parameter5, is_unavailable = @parameter6 
WHERE hash = 'xqA5jdsFBLPTrvy5kKHfgXBZdv9Hs2Ld' 
AND lastUpdated = '12-01-2016 15:53:47.3978486'
```